# Read/write csv file in Corel VBA script

Tags: vba, csv, coreldraw

It might be simple and all but I can't find any reference to reading and writing to a CSV file in Corel VBA.

Basically I have a TextBox which is there to set a folder path, a browse button and a save button in a form (there's a whole lot more stuff but that's not relevant right now). When the form loads the data that is in the CSV file is loaded as the value of that TextBox and set a as string variable "folderPath" if the user browse to a different folder path and clicks save then the value of the CSV file is overwritten and the CSV file is saved. The CSV has only one data in it.

There must be a way to do that, I can't believe it's not possible...

I combed through the API as much as I could. I even asked ChatGPT but obviously that was useless...

Comment: A CSV file is just a plain text file which follows some specific formatting rules, but those are irrelevant if your file only contains a single value.  There are plenty of references out there showing how to read/write text files from VBA.  Eg: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/text-file-macros/

Comment: I guess my search terms were bad. Got it working with that. Thanks